# Best way to transfert data from RDBMs to S3 by batch

Tags: amazon-s3, rdbms

I have a requirement to transfer data (frequency = one transfer every evening) from on-prem relational database (SQL server) to AWS S3 (As csv files and csv format is a requirement). The data size is around 500 GB. Given the absence of CDC, the entire database will be copied every evening.

Of course, we can think of formats like parquet or orc, but csv is a requirement in our use-case.

I thought to a JDBC link with an EMR-spark cluster to import data from the on-prem RDBMs database before transforming it into a csv and sending it to S3, but I am not sure that it is the most optimal architecture.

For JDBC, i do not know if there is a way to have several connections (btw emr-spark and sqlserver) in parallel to speed up the transfer.

It is a VPN connection which connects the on-prem site and the aws part.

Can someone suggest me the best way to have the fastest transfer respecting the principles of aws well-architected ?

Comment: Which **database engine** do you use? How much of the 500GB **changes** every day? That's a lot of data to transfer, so you'd want to minimize the data volume if possible. Can you tell us more about ***how you intend to use the CSV files** once they are in Amazon S3? This could impact your choice of compression, partitioning and file format. Feel free to edit your question to include this information rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: Thank you John Rotenstein, I added the additional information

Comment: My biggest concern would be the time taken to transfer this data. **What is the speed of your data link?** Even over 100 Mbps Ethernet it would take 11 hours. ([File Transfer Time Calculator - WintelGuy.com](https://wintelguy.com/transfertimecalc.pl))

Comment: Yes  John, unfortunately it will not exceed 100 Mbps. For this reason, I thought of another scenario: generate backups from the on-prem SqlServer database and compress them before passing them over the vpn. Then, create another SqlServer data base on the aws side, and finally extract the csv files from this data base. What do you think of this solution?

Comment: You should start by measuring how big these compressed files would be, to see whether they would fit within the desired transfer time. Can I also ask _WHY_ you wish to make 500GB of CSV files every day on Amazon S3? What will be consuming these files? If you provide more information, you are likely to receive a more-relevant answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using apache spark for transferring 500gb data is a big no as spark is more of processing large datasets than ingestion.

So AWS Glue should not be considered here.

Now you can use AWS EMR and perform a SQOOP import to your s3 bucket with more number of mappers as it would improve performance drastically and 500 GB data can be transferred in less than 2 hours depending on your rdbms configuration.

Other tools if you are using AWS than can be considered

1. Data Migration Service (DMS)
   This is fast and reliable way to transfer data on daily basis and it's configuration is also very easy.
   You can go through it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/DMS-SBS-Welcome.html).
2. Schema Conversion Tool (SCT)
   This is second aws recommend way to move data from rdbms to s3. You can use this convert your existing SQL scripts to redshift compatible and also you can move your data from rdbms to s3. This requires some expertise in setup. Read about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html).
3. SQOOP on EMR:
   This is my preferred way of migrating data but this will require you SQOOP knowledge. If you are comfortable with SQOOP then choose this option create your job as transient emr clusters and orchestrate using aws step functions.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/) or [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) to connect to the on-premises database and schedule spark jobs to move the data on daily basis to S3. I would recommend Glue to avoid the headache of managing the EMR cluster.